# JavaPOS : Cannot connect to printer

Tags: java, javapos

i'm very new to JavaPOS

When i try to init the printer i've got this error :

> "Could not create an instance"

I have installed the epson ADK 1.14.1, executed the JavaPOS.bat, create the xml file, set the property to link this file in my app :

```
System.setProperty(JposPropertiesConst.JPOS_POPULATOR_FILE_PROP_NAME, System.getProperty("jpos.xml.url"));
```

I have java8 (32bits). 
I try to connect :

```
POSPrinter printer = new POSPrinter();
printer.open("POSPrinter");
```

where printerLogicalName is the same as in .xml file :

```
<JposEntry logicalName="POSPrinter">
```

I've checked with the CheckHealth tool, this is working, something is printed...
I have no idea what to check...
Any idea?

My code :

```
private static final POSPrinter initPrinter(final String printerLogicalName) throws JposException {
    System.setProperty(JposPropertiesConst.JPOS_POPULATOR_FILE_PROP_NAME, System.getProperty("jpos.xml.url"));

    POSPrinter printer = new POSPrinter();
    printer.open("POSPrinter");
...
```

Edit : I managed to adapt a provided JavaPOS sample, and i can now print but only with a Java Application, and only outside eclipse (executing the .jar file).

If i run the app in eclipse i have the error : "Service does not exist in loaded JCL registry".

And concerning the webapp, i've tried to deploy it in a running tomcat (outside eclipse) but I have same error "Could not create an instance"

Comment: Have you managed to find a solution for your eclipse? Thanks

Comment: Nope, i just deployed my jar on a tomcat outside eclipse :/

Answer (score 2):

you need to set -Djava.library.path="path_to_dlls" in eclipse

Comment: It took me so many tries to finally get this working and now with this it worked. Just a comment the path can be directory. e.g. -Djava.library.path=../lib/